# Replacing all the dots in the name of directories and sub directories recursively with spaces

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Using bash I'm trying to replace all the dots in the name of directories and it's sub-directories with spaces.

Example: 
the directory **dir.1.3**
will become **dir 1 3**

Script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash    
for dir in *\ -\ *; do

      [[ -d "$dir" ]] || continue   # skip if not a directory
      sub="${dir#* - }"
      if [[ ! -e "$sub" ]]; then
        mv "$dir" "$sub"
        mv echo "$(echo "Result: ${dir%.*}" | sed 's/\./ /g').${dir##*.}"

      fi
done
```

Comment: It's not clear why you're looking for files with the pattern `* - *`, I added an answer using `find` and pattern `*.*` (a dot anywhere in the filename).

Comment: Are you sure that you want directories with the name that starts with a dot (hidden directories) to start with a space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `find`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -name "*.*" -exec bash -c '
  for ((i=$#;i>0;i--)); do
    dir=${!i}
    newdir=$(dirname "$dir")/$(basename "$dir" | tr -s "." " ")
    if [ -e "$newdir" ]; then
      echo "skipping \"$dir\", \"$newdir\" already exists" >&2 
    else
      mv "$dir" "$newdir"
    fi
  done
' bash {} +
```

This finds all directory names recursively with pattern `*.*` in the current directory skipping the current directory with `-mindepth 1`.
The list of found directories is passed with `-exec` to a bash script where its arguments are processed in reversed order in the for-loop (subdirectories with a deeper level come first).

The new directory name is created from its `dirname` and `basename`. The latter is modified with `tr` where multiple dots are replaced with one space character (remove option `-s` if you want to replace multiple dots with multiple spaces).
Then print an error message if the new directory name already exists or move it.